# moving DOM object with style.left

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple game in javascript, sort of a Pong game.

When I move the opponent paddle to the right, the movement isn't as smooth as it is when I move the paddle to the left.

There isn't really much to the updating of position

```
if(opponentDir === 'right'){  
counter += 1; 

if(counter === 80)
  opponentDir = 'left';
 }
else
{
 counter -= 1; 

 if(counter === 0)
   opponentDir = 'right';
}
```

and then the same drawing function applies, Game.draw.
Am I missing something with the use of style.left?

http://codepen.io/xonium/pen/qLDmj

So far i've only tested it in Chrome.

Comment: [position absolute vs transform](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)

Comment: Not really any help to why this occured

Comment: just a tip.. try adding -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0) .. this activates the gpu rendering on some browsers.and if your script allows it try to move the elements with it. i noticed alot of improvements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my drawing method.

Updating the velocity to reflect the movement direction of the paddle got me the disired result.

```
left = actualPixels + this.velocity * interpolation;
```